# DevExpress TreeList incremental search

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need to implement incremental search in treelist. The criterion is node's name contain specific string. I found this advise "You should override the FindNode method of the 
XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler.IncrementalSearchState class" from here http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/15735.aspx. But i don't understand how to realize this.

Comment: Traverse the tree nodes using either [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or breadth-first searching algorithm and match the node name against your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursive should give a solution to traverse the whole tree.

```
private TreeListNode GetNodeByName(TreeListNodes prmNodes, String prmName)
{
   foreach (TreeListNode node in prmNodes)
   {
      // Assume the data is present in column 0.
      if (node[0].ToString().Contains(prmName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
         return node;

      TreeListNode foundNode = GetNodeByName(node.Nodes, prmName);

      if (foundNode != null)
         return foundNode;
   }
   return null;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now if you do a simple call like:

```
TreeListNode node = GetNodeByName (treeList.Nodes, "MyNodeName");
```

you will get your desired node.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like:

```
public class MyTreeList : DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList
{

    protected override DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler CreateHandler()
    {
        return new MyHandler(this);
    }

    internal DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler GetHandler() { return this.Handler; }
}

public class MyHandler : DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler
{
    public MyHandler(TreeList tree) : base(tree) { }

    protected override TreeListControlState CreateState(TreeListState state)
    {
        if (state == TreeListState.IncrementalSearch && this.TreeList is MyTreeList)
            return new MyFinder((this.TreeList as MyTreeList).GetHandler());
        return base.CreateState(state);
    }
}

public class MyFinder : DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler.IncrementalSearchState
{
    public MyFinder(DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Handler.TreeListHandler handler) : base(handler) { }
    protected override TreeListNode FindNode(FindNodeArgs e)
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
        return base.FindNode(e);
    }
}
```